# How can I delete the unicode tags in my csv?

Tags: python, regex, csv, unicode, sed

I have a csv that looks like this:

```
"[u'Title, Volume.']",[u'19780620']
[u'Title 2.'],[u'19910607']
"[u'Catalogue.']",[u'19910429']
```

I want a csv that looks like this:

```
'Title, Volume.','19786020'
'Title 2.','199110607'
'Catalogue.','19910429'
```

I'd prefer to do this via Mac's terminal with sed + regex, but I suppose I could also use python. I've tried all kinds of regex, and this came the closest to solving at least the beginning character issues:

```
sed 's/[\"\[u]//g' file.csv
```

But it deletes *all* the 'u' characters--not just the ones in the beginning. How can I write a regex that gets to my desired result?

Comment: isn't that just a display issue, when it's written out to csv aren't the `u` prefixes removed?

Comment: Was hoping that was the case, but for some reason they're all displaying in any text editor I've used & excel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up running three separate sed commands because I'm not sure how to string them together, but got there in the end.

```
sed -ie 's/"//g' file.csv
sed -ie 's/\[[u]//g' file.csv
sed -ie 's/\]//g' file.csv
```

Any more elegant solutions are welcome!

Comment: Join them! `sed -e 's/"//g' -e 's/...' -e '...' file.csv`